# How to find an element which attribute has exact value and attribute name starts with given pattern with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I would like to find an element which attribute has exact value and attribute name starts with given pattern.

HTML:

```
<div class=col-xs-12>
    <select name=registrationProcedureCode tabIndex=-1 class="form-control selectized" id=registrationProcedureNew style="DISPLAY: none" data-bind="options: [''], value: registrationProcedureCode, optionsCaption: i2chCaption" jQuery1124022385363269720443="36" __ko__1582114720513="ko21">
        <option value="" selected></option>
    </select>
    <div class="selectize-control form-control single">
        <div class="selectize-input items not-full" jQuery1124022385363269720443="139">
            <input tabIndex=-32768 style="WIDTH: 337px" type=text autocomplete="off" placeholder="bla" jQuery1124022385363269720443="141">
        </div>
        <div class="selectize-dropdown single form-control" style="WIDTH: 627px; LEFT: 0px; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 34px" jQuery1124022385363269720443="136">
            <div class=selectize-dropdown-content></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And there are some other div elements with jQueryblabla attributes. 
So I need to find this **div element** with attribute value **139** and attribute name starting with **jQuery**.

I tried this line:

`//div[@*[starts-with(name(), 'jQuery')]='139']`

But it is wrong. Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: It seems you have a couple of typos there, but `//div[@*[starts-with(name(), 'jQuery')]='139']` should work.

Comment: @JackFleeting still unable to find element

Comment: Well, it definitely works on the html in your question, so try posting a little more of the html in which this `div` is located, so we can see the context.

Comment: @JackFleeting added more html code

Comment: It still works; depending on your xpath engine, the problem could be with the fact that the attribute is capitalized; try it with `starts-with(name(), 'jquery')` (lower case 'q').

Comment: @JackFleeting just tried the expression with lower case 'q'. It worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write my xpath expression is

```
//div[@*[starts-with(name(), 'jquery')]='139']
```

Cheers to @JackFleeting!